# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{n²+n+1}{n²+n-1})$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm just reviewing for my exam, unfortunately I couldn't resolve these two questions:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{n²+n+1}{n²+n-1})$
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n^4 + (-2)^n}$

I'm not that good in this topic so if you could your resolving I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here, We have rules. One of them is : Write your try, cause MSE is not a homework solution service or something like that :) Wish you the best :)

Comment: Other than posting the question here, what have you tried? If you include your working, we could help you with where you go wrong.

Comment: Also, please do not post multiple questions at once.

Comment: The first one is in a ln fonction. I tried to calculate the limite and found 0 but when I try to calculate the sum it seemed like infinite. And for the seconde one I think sin is bounded but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the multiple question. I didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1. Note that 
$$\ln\left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+n-1}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Now use the fact that $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$.

Hint 2.  Note that for $n> 16$,
$$\frac{|\sin n|}{|n^4 + (-2)^n|}\leq \frac{1}{2^n-n^4}\sim \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Comment: Thank you I understood the second one. But the first one's fraction is in ln, I couldn't modify it.

Comment: See my edited answer and try again. What is the limit?

Comment: In this case it's 1. I think it's diffirent when it's in log.

Answer (score 0):

For the first series, use *Taylor's expansion* at order $2$ and *equivalence of functions*:
\begin{align}
\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+n-1}&=\frac{1+\cfrac1n+\cfrac1{n^2}}{1+\cfrac1n-\cfrac1{n^2}}=\Bigl(1+\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)\biggl(1-\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)\biggr)\\
&=1-\frac1{n^2}+\frac2{n^2}+\frac1{n^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)=1+\frac2{n^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)
\end{align}
so $$\ln\Bigl(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+n-1}\Bigr)=\ln\Bigl(1+\frac2{n^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)\Bigr)=\frac2{n^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{n^2}\Bigr)\sim_\infty\frac2{n^2},$$
which converges.

The general term of the second series is $O\Bigl(\dfrac1{2^n}\Bigr)$, which is a convergent geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question that it's in the title. In future, please show some attempt. I'll give you a nudge. You know if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. (but you must keep in mind that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ does not necessarily imply that $\sum a_n$ converges) Try dividing the numerator and denominator by $n^2$, that might help, ie.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \log\left(\frac{n^2 + n + 1} {n^2 + n - 1}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \log\left(\frac {1 + \frac 1 n + \frac 1 {n^2} } {1 + \frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n^2}}\right)$$